# Emacs - how to format a block of text into spreadsheet form?

Tags: emacs, string-formatting

Is there a command/mode in emacs to format a block of text like this:

```
; before
; p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10
i 107 0 1 10000 440 1
i 107 1.5 1 20000 220 2
i 107 3 2 10000 110 2
i 107 3.5 2.5 10000 138.6 2
i 107 4 2 5000 329.6 2
i 107 4.5 1.5 6000 440 2
i 108 7 1 10000 440 1 2 3 1
i 108 8.5 1 10000 220 1 0.5 8 1
i 108 10 3 10000 110 1 1 13 1
i 108 10.5 2.5 10000 130.8 1 2.001 8 1
```

into this?

```
; after
; p1  p2   p3  p4    p5    p6 p7    p8 p9 p10
i 107 0    1   10000 440   1
i 107 1.5  1   20000 220   2
i 107 3    2   10000 110   2
i 107 3.5  2.5 10000 138.6 2
i 107 4    2   5000  329.6 2
i 107 4.5  1.5 6000  440   2
i 108 7    1   10000 440   1  2     3  1
i 108 8.5  1   10000 220   1  0.5   8  1
i 108 10   3   10000 110   1  1     13 1
i 108 10.5 2.5 10000 130.8 1  2.001 8  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `M-x table-capture`

Comment: I kind of think that table-capture is confusing. I tried it a couple of times, and I could not get it to work properly. Is there a way to run the command for a table without borders?

Comment: What did you do?  What happened?  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Nice! `M-x table-release` (with point *inside* a table cell) will remove the borders. This leaves you with a blank line between rows, which is easy to clean up.

Comment: Here is what I do: my column delimiter: s+ (one or more whitespace), my row delimiter ^ (end of line), justify left, minimum cell width 1. and I get a vertical line of p's. that's all. What I would like to get is already in the question; all cells lined up within a table, with no borders. thanks a lot

Comment: artsince: Your regexps are wrong. Firstly, Emacs regexps are not PCRE, and `\s+` does not mean whitespace. See `M-: (info "(elisp) Regexp Backslash")`. You want `\s-` (or just a plain space would do in this example). Secondly, `^` is not end-of-line in any regexp syntax I've seen; it's always start-of-line. You want `$`, or a newline (`C-q C-j`).

Comment: oh, of course. thank you very much for the detailed solution. My regex were entirely wrong...

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure it's the same but the org-mode has great table support

activate org-mode and try either one of those

- record a keyboard macro to add '|' between fields
  (if your tables arent sparse aka no empty cell)
- use regexp-replace to convert space into '|'

then play with it like in excel

ps: if you need more, just ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use emacs org-mode table support to create a table from the region, then delete the column separators once it's completed.

Highlight the region in question, then execute

```
M-x org-table-create-or-convert-from-region
```

Your results will look like this:

```
; before
| ; |  p1 |   p2 |  p3 |    p4 |    p5 | p6 |    p7 | p8 | p9 | p10 |
| i | 107 |    0 |   1 | 10000 |   440 |  1 |       |    |    |     |
| i | 107 |  1.5 |   1 | 20000 |   220 |  2 |       |    |    |     |
| i | 107 |    3 |   2 | 10000 |   110 |  2 |       |    |    |     |
| i | 107 |  3.5 | 2.5 | 10000 | 138.6 |  2 |       |    |    |     |
| i | 107 |    4 |   2 |  5000 | 329.6 |  2 |       |    |    |     |
| i | 107 |  4.5 | 1.5 |  6000 |   440 |  2 |       |    |    |     |
| i | 108 |    7 |   1 | 10000 |   440 |  1 |     2 |  3 |  1 |     |
| i | 108 |  8.5 |   1 | 10000 |   220 |  1 |   0.5 |  8 |  1 |     |
| i | 108 |   10 |   3 | 10000 |   110 |  1 |     1 | 13 |  1 |     |
| i | 108 | 10.5 | 2.5 | 10000 | 130.8 |  1 | 2.001 |  8 |  1 |     |
```

At this point, you can search and replace for the | character separating the columns to get

```
; before
;  p1   p2  p3    p4    p5 p6    p7 p8 p9 p10
i 107    0   1 10000   440  1                
i 107  1.5   1 20000   220  2                
i 107    3   2 10000   110  2                
i 107  3.5 2.5 10000 138.6  2                
i 107    4   2  5000 329.6  2                
i 107  4.5 1.5  6000   440  2                
i 108    7   1 10000   440  1     2  3  1    
i 108  8.5   1 10000   220  1   0.5  8  1    
i 108   10   3 10000   110  1     1 13  1    
i 108 10.5 2.5 10000 130.8  1 2.001  8  1
```